# Trigger System-wide Keyboard Events from a Javascript Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, keyboard-events

Is there a way to trigger a system-wide keyboard event (i.e. emulate an actual key being physically pressed) from a Javascript Chrome App?

Currently I've got

```
target.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(..));
```

but this can only be invoked on a target element within the browser.

Ultimately, I want to be able to have a callback

```
function typeLetter(character){ }
```

that will type a letter `character` whether Chrome is the active window or not.

Any suggestions greatly welcomed!

Comment: Yea, just let me send the keystrokes "win+r, c, m, d, enter, f, o, r, m, a, t...." - no issues there!  Letting javascript send keystrokes to the desktop would be insane.. sorry, but it's just never going to happen - and you should be glad about that :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this won't be possible between different applications. Even between browser tabs would be an issue I think.  If it were possible there would be plenty of security issues that come with it.

Emulating key presses anywhere except the currently-running application (chrome) would open up a can of worms in regards to cross-site scripting attacks and key-logging hacks.

Comment: Agh as I feared. I was hoping there might be a way requesting extra permissions in the manifest. Thanks.